Constructing infinite 3-connected quadrangulations containing only induced 4-cycles and induced 6-cycles.
Quadrangulations are planar graphs such that every face is of length 4.
We can construct infinitely many quadrangulations that contain only induced 4-cycles(the length of every induced cycle is at most 4) such as  $K_{2,t}$, shown in the following picture.

However, when the minimum degree is raised to 3 (or the connectivity is increased to 3), I have proved that any quadrangulation will contain induced cycles longer than 4. Moreover, I have found many graphs that contain only induced 4-cycles and 6-cycles using plantri.
For example, a cube with 8 vertices, or the follwoing graph (with graph6 form: VsaAJ@?W@?E_E?B??_?G??_CBC_BO?@o??F???K???W_)

But I am also trying to construct infinitely many of them.

Your second graph has an induced cycle of length $8$. Using graph6 vertex enumeration it is $0, 2, 7, 17, 22, 21, 15, 5, 0$

You are right. I list all non-isomorphic quadrangulations with minimum degree 3 and  longest induced cycles of length at most 6 in my github homepage https://github.com/lichengzhang1/qud

Edit: my initial construction was not planar, but I keep it under the line.
Take $k$ copies of $H = P_2\times P_3$. Add two adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$. Then for each copy connect $u$ with both ends of one $P_3$ and $v$ with both ends of the other $P_3$. After that for each copy except the last one add an edge between end vertex of $P_3$ adjacent to $u$ and end vertex of $P_3$ of the next copy adjacent to $v$. For inner copies two such vertices (incident to edges to the previous and to the next copies) should belong to different $P_2$'s and different $P_3$'s.
Alternative description is the following. Take $k$ copies of $8$ vertex cube. Select one edge in each of them. Contract the first ends of these edges into one vertex $v$ and the second ends of these edges into another vertex $u$. Discard multiple edges $uv$ and keep only one of them. Select two vertices other than $u$ and $v$ at distance $3$ in each copy. Add edge between selected vertex adjacent to $u$ and selected vertex of the next copy adjacent to $v$. (For the first and last copies ignore one of selected vertices, or ignore both in the only copy for $k = 1$.)
Resulting graph is planar bipartite and has $6k + 2$ vertices, $12k$ edges, $4$ vertices per face, and minimum degree $3$. Each induced cycle contains either

neither $u$ nor $v$, thus belongs entirely to only one copy of $H$ and has length $4$ or $6$;
or exactly one of $u$ and $v$ (WLOG it is $u$) and has other vertices in either

one copy of $H$ and has length $4$ or $6$,
or two adjacent copies of $H$, but exactly one vertex in one of them, and has length $4$ or $6$;


or both $u$ and $v$, and therefore one vertex adjacent to $u$, one vertex adjacent to $v$, and zero or two more vertices, and still has length $4$ or $6$.


Take $k$ copies of the $8$ vertex cube. Select two vertices at distance $3$ in each copy. Contract all first such vertices into vertex $u$ and all second vertices into vertex $v$.
Another description of the same graph is the following: take $k$ copies of $C_6$, add two vertices $u$ and $v$ and connect $u$ with all odd vertices of each copy of $C_6$ and $v$ with all even vertices of each copy of $C_6$.
Resulting graph is bipartite and has $6k + 2$ vertices, $12k$ edges and minimum degree $3$. Each induced cycle either contains neither $u$ nor $v$ and has length $6$, or contains exactly one of $u$ and $v$ and has length $4$, or contains both $u$ and $v$, and therefore two vertices adjacent to $u$, two vertices adjacent to $v$ and no other vertex, thus also has length $6$.
P. S. For $k \ge 2$ cycle $C_6$ can be replaced by $C_4$ with the same effect or equivalently cube can be replaced by $K_{3, 3} - e$.

Sorry,  are your graph planar? Quadrangulations are planar graphs such that every face is of length 4.

@licheng, Sorry, I didn't mention that you need quadrangulation. I will think a bit more

Thanks. It is my fault that I didn’t give the definition first.

@licheng I've updated my answer

I think it is right.
